# Removing duplicate blank lines with awk

Tags: awk

For one of my problems for class, I have a file where I am to delete duplicate blank lines in a file. so for example, I have an input file that looks like this:

```
Sample Line 1



Sample line 2

Sample line 3
```

and the output would then turn all multiple blank lines into a singular one, so the output file would look like this:

```
Sample Line 1

Sample line 2

Sample line 3
```

I've been able to complete this with a sed command, but the problem insists that I use awk in order to obtain this output.
The closest I've gotten has been with `awk '!x[$0]++'`, but that simply deletes pretty much every blank line. I feel like I'm missing something basic.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Set a variable when you process a blank line, and unset it when you see  non-blank line. Then skip printing the line only when the variable is already set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NF{c=1} (c++)<3' file
Sample Line 1

Sample line 2

Sample line 3
```

or if you don't mind an extra blank line at the end:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '1' file
Sample Line 1

Sample line 2

Sample line 3
```

Comment: My answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74658898/445221

Comment: @konsolebox that's a pretty bold claim. Why is that your opinion?

Comment: It's simpler and direct to the point, and it can be configured to include or exclude initial blank lines.

Comment: @konsolebox Mine are simpler and direct to the point and can be configured to leave N blank lines rather than just 1. The second one is also using the idiomatic awk paragraph mode designed to handle such cases. We don't know what the OPs requirements are for blank lines so we don't know if your script can be configured to do what the OP needs (e.g. if it's to compress all leading blank lines to 1) and mine can be tweaked to do whatever might be needed if leading blank lines were actually a concern, which the OP has given no indication that they are.

Comment: Allowing more than 1 blank line is unnecessary configurability and it doesn't make things simpler or direct to the point. Your answer is simply complicated as it is since it has to use awkward comparison with an n+2 parameter and a post-increment operation. How can you even defend that complexity. Your second answer is invalid as it always leaves another blank line. It doesn't matter if it's idiomatic.

Comment: @konsolebox your are giving your opinions on things that the OP hasn't provided requirements about, and claiming one solution is better than the other just based on your own preferences. I have other preferences and other guesses at things the OP may want. You think your answer is better, I think mine is. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!NF{found++} found>1 && !NF{next} NF{found=""} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Sample Line 1

Sample line 2

Sample line 3
```

Comment: Even with @Quasímodo's sample. ++

Answer (score 1):

This also works if the file has duplicate lines at beginning or end.

```
awk '
NF==0{
    if (! blank) {print;blank=1}
    next
}
{blank=0;print}
' file
```

The base for its operation is that `NF` is zero for every blank/empty line  with the default awk separator.

---

For example, if file is:

```
Sample Line 1



Sample line 2

Sample line 3
Sample line 4
```

it becomes

```
Sample Line 1

Sample line 2

Sample line 3
Sample line 4
```

Comment: Only one so far that handles several leading empty lines correctly.

Comment: @JamesBrown Not anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74658898/445221

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NF || p; { p = NF }' p=1 file
```

For modifying multiple files at once:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE { p = 1 } NF || p; { p = NF }' file ...
```

Exclude `p=1` or set initial value of `p` to `0` to also remove starting blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1  
 2  
 3  Sample Line 1
 4  
 5  
 6  
 7  Sample line 2
 8  
 9  
10  
11  
12  Sample line 3
13  Sample Line 4
14  
15
```

> ```
> mawk 'ORS = "\n\n"' RS=
> ```

```
 1  Sample Line 1
 2  
 3  Sample line 2
 4  
 5  Sample line 3
 6  Sample Line 4
 7
```